# CodeIgniter SQLite where field IN array condition

Tags: database, sqlite, codeigniter, pdo, where-clause

I'm having some trouble trying to set a 'WHERE field IN ...' clause in CodeIgniter using SQLite. I got an array of all where clause conditions called $conditions, and added the WHERE IN clause in this way:

```
$this->browse_model->conditions['username IN'] = "(SELECT like_to FROM likes WHERE like_from = '".$this->user->username."')";
```

and inside of my browse_model I use the following code to run the query:

```
$get = $this->db->get_where('users', $this->conditions, 6, $_SESSION['browse_page']*6);
```

but somehow when I use the condition I wrote above it is giving me the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in
>   ../www/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php on line 193

As far as I'm concerned the 'field IN array' statement is allowed in SQLite too, so I really don't know why this isn't working. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Greets,
Skyfe.

EDIT: Tried setting the condition in the following way and didn't get an error but neither any results:

```
$this->browse_model->conditions['username'] = "IN (SELECT like_to FROM likes WHERE like_from = '".$this->user->username."')";
```

So I guess that's still not the correct way to do it..

EDIT2: 'Fixed' it, somehow it didn't interpetate the field => value way of notating the where clause correctly for the IN statement, so defined it in a custom string:

```
$this->browse_model->custom_condition = username IN (SELECT like_to FROM likes WHERE like_from = '".$this->user->username."')
```

Comment: Please ensure that, database loader is loaded before?

Comment: Yes the database is loaded, all other queries do work, just not the one where I set the condition WHERE username IN array mentioned in my post. However I just tried putting the IN statement inside of the value and it didn't give an error, but neither returned any results (which it should)... So still confused

Comment: print the last query, that how it formated it {echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;}

Comment: Just did it, outputted: SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender = 'f' AND gender_preference = 'm' AND username = 'IN (SELECT like_to FROM likes WHERE like_from = ''testtest'')'

Comment: Fixed it in a different way, creating a custom overriding query which is set in normal string format rather than array

Comment: yeah definatly, their is some problem in formatting the query username "= IN"

Answer (score 0):

Their is some problem in formatting IN clause,

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender = 'f' AND gender_preference = 'm' AND username IN (SELECT like_to FROM likes WHERE like_from = 'testtest')
```